# Transferring files over home network WiFi

Tags: wireless, transfer

I've got 2 PCs with Linux distributions installed (one has Ubuntu 17.04 the other Mint 17.3) and I'd like to know how to transfer files between one another over my WiFi-network.

I would like to do that without having to install programs or using GUIs; 
I want to use the terminal.

Comment: You can do this with samba or any network protocol (http, ftp, ssh (scp), sshfs, etc). I thinks only samba requires no installation of packages, but I am not certain.

Comment: Use SCP - described here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/560777/how-to-copy-files-between-two-computers-using-ssh https://askubuntu.com/questions/329370/using-scp-to-copy-files-from-remote-to-home-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly beyond what you are asking for, but I would recommend that you **install the program package `openssh-server` into one of the computers**. I know that it is easy to install and works well in Ubuntu, because I use it.

Connect from the other computer via the program **`sftp`** to transfer files (or via **`ssh`** to log in and run programs remotely). This can be done completely via the command line (in a terminal which you wish now, or via GUI program if you wish later on).

These backup tools are designed to work well with an ssh server: **`rsync`** and **Clonezilla**.

The following links describe installing openssh-server and using sftp, ssh with more details,

- [help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html)
- [How do you send and receive data from one machine to another?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922592/how-do-you-send-and-receive-data-from-one-machine-to-another/922598#922598)
- [Filezilla crashes ubuntu 16.04 lts- Please suggest alternate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897301/filezilla-crashes-ubuntu-16-04-lts-please-suggest-alternate/897305#897305)
- [What is the simplest way to have remote GUI access to Ubuntu 16.04 “server” from Ubuntu 16.04 “desktop”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398)

Comment: @IDK, Please notice that the backup tools rsync and Clonezilla work well with an ssh server, if you wish to backup via the local [wireless] network.

Comment: thanks for the advice in the comment, I've actually done a local backup with tar  and I'd need a little help to figure some things out.                                                 I've edited my question  here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/954245/back-up-ubuntu-17-04

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you want to transfer files from system **A** to system **B**

- Find IP address of system **A** (wireless)

  > ifconfig
- Go to the directory you have the files to share

  > cd /directory
- Start that directory as HTTP server

  > python -m SimpleHTTPServer
- Go to system **B** and install `links` (terminal browser) package

  > sudo apt-get install links
- Start `links` with system **A** IP (assuming 192.168.2.1) and port which shows in third step (probably 8000)

  > links 192.168.2.1:8000
- Download whatever files you want

If security is not your concern and simply want to transfer files without any configuration, this is perfect for you, I guess.

Comment: No such module looks like. Deprecated?

Comment: The SimpleHTTPServer module has been merged into http.server in Python 3.0. So, your command is python -m http.server, or depending on your installation, it can be: python3 -m http.server.